# Associating 2 lists

Tags: python, list

I'm creating 2 lists out of some `re.findall` running on a string.

```
jobids = re.findall(r'R=(\d+)', (str(key['Job Dependencies'])))
jobdeps = re.findall(r'J=(\d+)', (str(key['Job Dependencies'])))
```

These both create a list like so:

```
['14866152', '0', '0', '14866149', '0', '14866156']
['75205', '52336', '75208', '75207', '75197', '75200']
```

The lists will always have the same number of elements in the case above that's `6`.

What I want to do is scan the first list and if it's a `0` I want the number from the second list at the same value.

I'm guessing I need to do something like:

```
for key in jobids:
    if key == '0':
        print jobdeps
```

But that returns the whole list and I don't want it.  I want in the example above 3 separate returns of `'52336'`, `'75208'` and `'75197'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zip()` is your friend:

```
for key, val in zip(jobids, jobdeps):
    if key == '0':
        print val
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
for index, key in enumerate(jobids):
    if key == '0':
        print jobdeps[index]
```

Comment: that awkward moment when both of us wrote the exact same answer xD

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> jobids = ['14866152', '0', '0', '14866149', '0', '14866156']
>>> jobdeps = ['75205', '52336', '75208', '75207', '75197', '75200']
>>> [y for x, y in zip(jobids, jobdeps) if x == '0']
['52336', '75208', '75197']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
>>> [jobdeps[i] for i,j in enumerate(jobids) if j=='0']
['52336', '75208', '75197']
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check for the index corresponding to the key , in your case you are printing out the whole array.

*This should help you out*

```
for index, key in enumerate(jobids):
    if key == '0':
        print jobdeps[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'zip' function is handy here.

```
for jobid, jobdep in zip(jobids, jobdeps):
    if jobid == '0':
        print jobdep
```

You might also try using enumerate(), e.g.

```
for idx, jobid in enumerate(jobids)
     if jobid == '0':
         print jobdeps[idx]
```